# error: id cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

i have created these button but getting the error of "error: id cannot be resolved or is not a field" in every line of(// buttons) and "error: layour cannot be resolved or is not a field" of (r.layou.main) hwever dont see any errors my layout keypad.xml

keypad.Java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        //Buttons
        one= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_1);
        two= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_2);
        three= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_3);
        four= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_4);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_5);
        six= (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_6);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_7);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_8);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_9);
        minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_subtract);
        hash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_hash);
```

keypad.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="45sp">
 </TextView>

<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/keypad"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="*" >

        //setting up keypad buttons one, two and three in one row
<TableRow>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_1"
android:text="@string/keypad_1" >
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_2"
android:text="@string/keypad_2" >
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_3"
android:text="@string/keypad_3" >
</Button>
</TableRow>
        //setting up keypad buttons 4,5 and 6 in second row
<TableRow>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_4"
android:text="@string/keypad_4" >
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_5"
android:text="@string/keypad_5" >
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_6"
android:text="@string/keypad_6" >
</Button>
</TableRow>

        //setting up keypad buttons 7,8 and 9 in third row
<TableRow>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_7"
android:text="@string/keypad_7" >
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_8"
android:text="@string/keypad_8" >
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_9"
android:text="@string/keypad_9" >
</Button>
</TableRow>
        //setting up keypad buttons del,0,# and - in forth row
<TableRow>
    <Button android:id="@+id/delete"
android:text="@string/keypad_DEL" >
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_0"
android:text="@string/keypad_0" >
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_hash"
android:text="@string/keypad_#" >
</Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/keypad_subtract"
android:text="@string/keypad_-" >
</Button>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/incorrect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/incorrect" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its tough to tell from what you've posted where the problem could be. A few things to try: Right click on your project in eclipse and select "clean Project". Also ensure that you are not importing any sort of R

Comment: thank mate... solved!! i had a private field of object R thats why...

Answer (score 1):

It seems project is not compiled yet. Clean your project by right click on project. If no compilation errors(red marks) in xml, clean should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that this error occurs because you have named string and id the same?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong .xml file for your layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

should be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.keypad);
```

also, are you creating the buttons above your onCreate method before you tie them to an id?

```
private Button one;
private Button two;
// and the rest of them...
```